# Public key to ethereum address in javascript without (or minified sha3 library)

Tags: web3js

I am trying to get rid of the web3js library and this is the last hurdle.
Before i used `web3.utils.keccak256(eth_public key)`
How can i do this with minimal amount of code in javascript.
I tried https://github.com/emn178/js-sha3 but no match...

Edit: I managed the hash by converting to binary string first.